# Function Arguments are used as statements

Tags: c

I saw a specific piece of code

```
Int SensorxyzOpen(SensorHandle          *handle_ptr,
                      struct SensorCallback *client_callback_ptr,
                      BOOL                     testcalibrated,
                      void                     *contextptr)
{
(void)handle_ptr;
(void)client_callback_ptr;
(void)testcalibrated;
(void)contextptr;

 return ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED;
}
```

What is this function doing ? How the function arguments can be used as statements

Comment: Those references don't really do anything.  They are probably there to avoid "argument not used" warnings from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

**Those statements have no real effects.** 
`(void)variable` It's just a way of avoiding complains about **unused variables** from the compiler. Casting to `void`  it's a way of referencing a variable in a harmless way i.e. without causing any side effects and still muting the warnings. 
Note that some compilers might mute the *variable not used* warning and raise the *not used value* warning since the value is referenced but not used.

I have seen people use also stuff like self-assignment like `variable1=variable1`.

---

As an aside note that in order to mute *unused variable* warnings for specific variables and you are using `gcc` or `clang` you can decorate a function parameter with  `__attribute__((unused))`  as shown in the following example:

```
int foo (__attribute__((unused)) int no_warning, double raise_a_warning) {
    return 0;
}
```